# How to reveal a certain effect using for loop (DirectX)

Tags: c++, directx, directx-9

I have a school project to make a game on DirectX 9. We are making a project in a team and they gave me a task to reveal a certain effect using for loop.

**This is a list of effects**

```
EFK_CHAR efk_filename[][MAX_PATH] =
    {
    u"asset/texture/エフェクト案/Dunk.efk",                   //0
     u"asset/texture/エフェクト案/BAD.efk",                   //1
     u"asset/texture/エフェクト案/block.efk",                 //2
    u"asset/texture/エフェクト案/combinationSelect.efk",      //3
     u"asset/texture/エフェクト案/pass.efk",                  //4
      u"asset/texture/エフェクト案/Perfect.efk",              //5
      u"asset/texture/エフェクト案/SonicBoom.efk",            //6
       u"asset/texture/エフェクト案/wind.efk",                //7
    };
```

**And this code is located in int Effect_Init. It reveals effect Dunk.efk**

```
effect = Effekseer::Effect::Create(manager, efk_filename[0]);
```

The teacher said I had to create an array that would contain indexes of EFK_CHAR efk_filename and make a for loop. So I can call a certain effect from all of these effects in main.cpp. For example, if I want to reveal an effect with index 7 when I press  P button.

I dont really understand so I wrote:

```
EFK_CHAR efk_filename[][MAX_PATH] =
{
u"asset/texture/エフェクト案/Dunk.efk",                   //0
 u"asset/texture/エフェクト案/BAD.efk",                   //1
 u"asset/texture/エフェクト案/block.efk",                 //2
u"asset/texture/エフェクト案/combinationSelect.efk",      //3
 u"asset/texture/エフェクト案/pass.efk",                  //4
  u"asset/texture/エフェクト案/Perfect.efk",              //5
  u"asset/texture/エフェクト案/SonicBoom.efk",            //6
   u"asset/texture/エフェクト案/wind.efk",                //7
}; 

EFK_CHAR Effect_Count[8] = { 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7 }; //Does this array contain the indexes of EFK_CHAR efk_filename[][MAX_PATH]?
```

And I am not sure about a for loop. I know that inside the loop I have to write `effect = Effekseer::Effect::Create(manager, efk_filename[i]);`. Can I write something like `for(int i = 0; i > EFK_CHAR, i ++)`?

Answer (score 0):

That mostly depends on what your teacher had in mind, which is hard to guess, but here are some possible options.

If you want to just iterate over a whole array of your filenames, just do this:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < MAX_PATH; i++)
{
  auto effect = Effekseer::Effect::Create(manager, efk_filename[i]);
  // do something with that effect, maybe to check if the button was pressed
  // or something like that?
  // if (button_pressed)
  // {
  //   applyEffect(effect);
  // }
}
```

Another possibility is that you need to take into account only some particular effect from the effect list, which can be done with the list of indices (let's say that you only want iterate over effects no 1, 3, and 5):

```
#define NUM_EFFECTS 3  // or constexpr NUM_EFFECTS = 3; if you prefer
size_t idx_array[NUM_EFFECTS] = {1, 3, 5};

for (size_t i = 0; i < NUM_EFFECTS; i++)
{
  auto effect = Effekseer::Effect::Create(manager, efk_filename[idx_array[i]]);
  // do something with the effect
}
```

Unfortunately, I am not sure how to understand "reveal an effect with index 7 when I press P button". Maybe it is about creating a map key <--> index, like `{'P', 7}`? If it is, you can use `std::map<char, size_t> key_map;` for that and pick your effect like this `efk_filename[key_map['P']]`.

Comment: Thank you so much! I will try to reveal effect now

Comment: It works! I tried the second one and it worked, but when I use auto effect = Effekseer::Effect::Create(manager, efk_filename[idx_array[i]]); it doesnt reveal any effect. However without using "auto" it works. Thank you so much again!